# android integrating library app

Tags: android, manifest

I am trying to integrate an open source app into my android app. I have made the open source app as a library app and integrated the xml into my android manifest file as well. There are no compile errors.

First Screen is the login screen for the library app and when it is called it is throwing java lang class exception error at:

```
m_app = (TodoApplication) getApplication();
```

source code of loginscreen.java:

```
public class LoginScreen extends Activity {

final static String TAG = LoginScreen.class.getSimpleName();

private TodoApplication m_app;
private Button m_LoginButton;
private BroadcastReceiver m_broadcastReceiver;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    m_app = (TodoApplication) getApplication();

    // supposed to help with the banding on the green background



    findViewById(R.id.loginbackground).getBackground().setDither(true);

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction("com.todotxt.todotxttouch.ACTION_LOGIN");
    m_broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, TodoTxtTouch.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    };
    registerReceiver(m_broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);

    m_LoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    m_LoginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            login();
        }
    });

    //final RemoteClient remoteClient = m_app.getRemoteClientManager()
        //  .getRemoteClient();
    //if (remoteClient.isAuthenticated()) {



        switchToTodolist();
    //}
}

private void switchToTodolist() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TodoTxtTouch.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(m_broadcastReceiver);
}


void login() {
    final RemoteClient client = m_app.getRemoteClientManager()
            .getRemoteClient();

    if (!client.isAvailable()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Remote service " + client.getClass().getSimpleName()
                + " is not available; aborting login");
        Util.showToastLong(m_app, R.string.toast_login_notconnected);
    } else {
        RemoteLoginTask loginTask = client.getLoginTask();
        loginTask.showLoginDialog(this);
    }
}

}
```

Integrated library code in android manifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name="com.todotxt.todotxttouch.LoginScreen" android:label="@string/app_label"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">     
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="com.todotxt.todotxttouch.category.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />            
        </intent-filter>


    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.todotxt.todotxttouch.TodoApplication" /> 

    <activity android:name="com.todotxt.todotxttouch.Filter" android:label="Filter"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity android:name="com.todotxt.todotxttouch.Preferences" android:label="@string/set_preferences" />
    <activity android:name="com.todotxt.todotxttouch.AddTask" android:label="@string/addtask"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity-alias android:name="com.todotxt.todotxttouch.AddTaskShortcut"
        android:targetActivity="com.todotxt.todotxttouch.AddTask" android:label="@string/shortcut_addtask_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity-alias>
    <activity-alias android:name="com.todotxt.todotxttouch.AddTaskShare"
        android:targetActivity="com.todotxt.todotxttouch.AddTask" android:label="@string/share_addtask_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity-alias>
    <activity android:name="com.todotxt.todotxttouch.HelpActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <activity android:name="com.todotxt.todotxttouch.TodoTxtTouch" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
```

Could anyone please help me on understanding the problem.

Let me explain further: I am having a file called Todoapplication.java....so the class exists...it being called from LoginScreen.java as

```
m_app = (TodoApplication) getApplication();
```

and that is where I am getting java lang class exception?

Answer (score 0):

`Activity.getApplication()` returns an instance of the application class that was declared in the manifest in the `<application>` element. I don't see it in your pasted manifest.

It's not enough to simply *have* the application class in your app. It must be explicitly designated as one in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

I maybe getting the wrong end of the stick so I beg the programming gods for forgiveness in advance.

Assuming you are developing in Eclipse, is this not a simple case of having a project in Eclipse with the open source source in, which within the project properties has the option isLibrary ticked.

In YOUR project's properties you can add a library and Eclipse will list the open source one (and any others that have the "isLibrary" checked). Would you not simply select the open source project and add it. Your project will then add the library and build again?

To access the open source project, now a library, you can use "import" statements to access any public methods that are exposed.

A good example of this setup process using an open source library project is Actionbar Sherlock to which I wrote a tutorial youtube that demonstrates visually what I have just written. It can be found at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=avcp6eD_X2k